# Propagating ng-invalid class update to child elements

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have build custom form control which works well. However when i hook it up with inbuilt angular validators I am facing issues. I am expecting that when validation fails angular should set all the elements from the root of the custom component to last child as invalid. However I am facing this issue below 
[image]

The parent control shows ng-invalid but has the class ng-untouched. Whereas the input shows ng-touched and ng-valid.

What I need is the input element to have ng-invalid set on validation failure.

My Angular 2 form binding are as below

html

```
<phone-control [formControl]="form.controls['phone']" type="number"></phone-control>
```

ts 
  phone: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(10),Validators.maxLength(10)])],

Can some help me understand what I am missing here.

Comment: Just curious have you found an answer?

Comment: What i did was implement my own class for validation error based of the result. That is the best i could come up with

Comment: You mean custom validator?

Comment: Yeah custom validator or custom form component. I built a custom form component since i needed it for SSN number. I checked for validation error and then replaced my custom class manually in the html